# How to Parse &#DDDDD;&#DDDDD; (Unicode Image) with XML Parser

Tags: xml, parsing, unicode, libxml2

I face to the one weird issue, I get XML data as INPUT such as

```
<D\DATA>
<\DATA_CONTENT="&lt;p&gt;&#55357;&#56842;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&#55357;&#56832;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&#55357;&#56865;&lt;/p&gt;"/>
<\/DATA>
```

and try to parse with libxml2

```
xmlReaderForMemory(inputData.c_str(),inputData.length(),NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

the problme is xml parser can`t process the parsing because of "&"
image string in sample input is "&#55357;&#56865;' is UTF-8 encoded UNICODE or HTML data so data is correct, 
but problem is "&" is not possible in XML Data. it shoulde be changed as "&amp;" but i can`t change the input data.

the data is made in android system with TransformerFactory() and able to parse via DOM on JAVA

but i need to parse it in C/C++. so i`m try to parse the xml data with libxml2 but...no way to solve this issue..

Please help me and thanks in advance

Comment: Your data is not even valid XML, not even a part of it, whatever that is.

Comment: that is just sample datat not full data if i change the &#DDDDD data as normal text it`s okay to parse..

Answer (score 2):

`&#55357;` (U+D83D) and `&#56842;` (U+DE0A) are numeric character references for [Unicode surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2BD800_to_U.2BDFFF) which are [not allowed in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets). So *libxml2* does the right thing when it rejects such character references.

You should change the part of the code that produces this invalid XML by combining the surrogates first. For example, the surrogate pair `D83D DE0A` is the UTF-16 encoding of code point [U+1F60A: SMILING FACE WITH SMILING EYES](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f60a/index.htm). Your XML producer should output `&#x1F60A;` or in decimal `&#128522;`.

Comment: Thanks! i`m chekcing how to change the Unicode Surrogte(&#55357;&#56842) to Unicode(U+1F60A)